# RSpec + Spork on Win give no output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, spork

guys.

```
Rails 3.2.12
```

I have a sample test **spec/models/user_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"
end
```

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'

  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
    config.order = "random"
    config.color_enabled = true
    config.tty = true
    config.formatter = :documentation # :progress, :html, :textmate  
  end
end

Spork.each_run do
end
```

When I run the test **without** Spork I get:

```
$ rspec
c:/ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support
/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require': iconv will be deprecated in the futu
re, use String#encode instead.

User
  add some examples to (or delete) d:/sites/efiling/spec/models/user_spec.rb (PE
NDING: No reason given)

Pending:
  User add some examples to (or delete) d:/sites/efiling/spec/models/user_spec.r
b
    # No reason given
    # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:4

Finished in 0.31249 seconds
1 example, 0 failures, 1 pending

Randomized with seed 10437
```

When I run the test **with** Spork I get:

```
$ rspec . --drb
  <-- Slave(1) run done!
```

In Spork window:

```
Loading Spork.prefork block...
  --> DRb magazine_slave_service: 1 provided...
Running tests with args ["--color", "."]...
  <-- take tuple(1); slave.run...
   -- (1);run done
Done.

   -- build slave 1...
Preloading Rails environment
```

**Why does Rspec give no info about pending, failed etc tests when I use it with Spork?**

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to your question: [How can I configure rspec to show output with spork?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239382/how-can-i-configure-rspec-to-show-output-with-spork)

For your convenience, the way posted to circumvent this error is to add this to the Spork.each_run block:

```
if Spork.using_spork?
    RSpec.configure do |config|
        config.reset
        config.output_stream = $stdout
    end
end
```

I had the same problems as you, and once I added this in, I was getting normal output again.